# Playing voicemail via MediaPlayer turns alarm volume silent

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-alarms

I play an audio file from a URL using MediaPlayer. The file plays fine, however after playback (if the app hasnt't been explicitly killed), alarm ringtone is silent. What do I need to clear/reset on end of playback to make this not happen?

Code for the file I am using to control the voicemail playback.
http://hastebin.com/ehijobuwoc.coffee

Comment: if it can help, try to add setOnCompletionListener() method of media player and reset the values in this....

Comment: @DeepakGoyal as you can see I have that, and I don't think it is doing anything. Also potentially the voicemail may not be played all the way.

Comment: You are using `setSpeakerphoneOn(false)`, you should probably set it back to true as soon as stopping the playback.

Comment: Thought that might be it @ozbek but unfortunately that didn't do anything. In fact just calling that, even without playing the voicemail broke it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok have found something that works. Solves both the alarm issue and allows me to play the voicemail through the earpiece.

I needed to setMode back to what it was when I started, in onStop():

```
// set mode back to normal, and speakerphone back to true.
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setMode(prevMode);
am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

and in init:

```
private void initMediaPlayer() {
    // Make the media play through earpiece instead of through speaker(default)
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    prevMode = am.getMode();
    am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
    am.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
```

Thanks @DreadfulWeather for leading me to this answer, with some helpful questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getStreamVolume at start of playback then use setStreamVolume to set it back after your playback has finished.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume(int, int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamVolume(int,%20int,%20int))

Comment: Nope, didn't do anything.

Comment: May i ask why do you call setMode and setSpeakerPhoneOn methods ? And can you also try using getRingerMode at start then using setRingerMode at finish with returned value from getRingerMode ?

Comment: should I not be using setMode/setSpeakerPhoneOn? Ok so I figured at least something out, the way I have the code right now, lets me play the media through earpiece instead of the speakerphone. If I comment out setMode(it plays through speaker and the alarm doesn't break)... But I need both.

Comment: In documentation it says setMode/setSpeakerPhoneOn  should only be used by applications that replace the platform-wide management of audio settings or the main telephony application. I think you should not use both of them and it will automatically play on earpiece if earpiece plugged in or speaker if it is not.

Comment: Not quite a solution, but yes I think it may be the issue. The requirement is to play the voicemail not over speaker.

Comment: Then you can check it like in the link and dont play audio if the route is speaker [link](https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-output.html)